# Loosing alignments

Tags: flutter, dart

In the following code, by uncommenting `// return child;` the `Alignment` works, but when wrapping `child` with `Column` we loose the `Alignment`

Why? and how to fix it?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final child = Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.blue),
        ),
        Container(width: 100, height: 500, color: Colors.red),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Container(width: 100, height: 300, color: Colors.green),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(width: 100, height: 200, color: Colors.yellow),
        ),
        Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.purple),
      ],
    );
    
    // return child;
    
    return Column(
      children: [
        child,
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below will solve your problem. I just wrapped the 'child' widget with 'Expanded'.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final child = Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.blue),
        ),
        Container(width: 100, height: 500, color: Colors.red),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Container(width: 100, height: 300, color: Colors.green),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(width: 100, height: 200, color: Colors.yellow),
        ),
        Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.purple),
      ],
    );
    
    // return child;
    
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(child: child,),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't want expand my child, Also `Flexible` is not working as expected,  wrapping with `IntrinsicHeight` is the solution, But Why?!